# parameter access_type :when it should be online , when offline

Tags: c#, parameters, google-plus

When we add `sign in with google+` button into our site , we should specify `access_type`. 
Can anyone explain , what is the `access_type`. 
When it should be `online` , when `offline`.
 I don't want any link. I have read from google.com.
But I want to understand `access_type` with any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They change the tokens returned when you exchange the one time code in OAuth2.

- Online: Only ever returns an access token.
- Offline: May[^] return a refresh token as well as an access token.

An access token lasts for 1 hour, and can be used to make API calls to Google APIs on behalf of the user. A refresh token lasts for a long time (effectively till revoked, or if not used for a long time) and can be used to create more access tokens, even when the user is not directly using the app. Hence it can be used for access when the user is "offline". You should use this if you want to do work on the server when the user is not using the app - for example if you were syncing calendar entries from one system to a user's calendar.

[^] "May" because a refresh token is only returned if the user sees a consent screen. So, the first time the user signs in they will consent, and a refresh token will be returned. The second time they will be smoothly signed in without further consent, and the exchange will just return an access token. This is why it is important to store the refresh token in a persistent store like a database.

Comment: IN my project when user sing in with `google+ `, I get user's data and I add those data into my `USERS class` that I use it as `Session`. Already everytime when user sign in, I will have `access_token` for one hour. And I need only 0..1 second to get user's data. 

I think that I don't need `offline acceess_type`.
hm ?

Comment: Yep, sounds like you only need online access